# In ng 2 chart during the load an undefined legend gets created automatically ,Is there any way to remove it?

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

In the ng-2 chart during the load an undefined legend gets created automatically in the stacked bar , with the color that I have not mentioned, I am using a set of a particular color defined in an array so is there any way by which it can be removed? only the undefined label.

```
public barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    legend:{
       display:true
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
      }]
    },
    layout: {
      padding: {
          left: 0,
          right: 20,
          top: 30,
          bottom: 0
      }
    }
  };
  public mainBarChartLabels: Label[] = [];
  public mainBarChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [];
  public barChartType: ChartType = 'bar';
  public barChartLegend = true;
  public barChartPlugins = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {  
    this.MainData();
  }
MainData(): void {
    var data=[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]];
    this.mainBarChartLabels = []
    this.mainBarChartData = []
    let param ={
      type : this.mainDataDuration?this.mainDataDuration:1,
      startDate: '',
      endDate: ''
    }
    this.mainService.getnamenCount(param).subscribe(data => {
      let a=Array();
      for(let i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
        for(let j=0;j<data[i].names.length;j++){
          if (!(a.includes(data[i].names[j].Name))){
            a.push(data[i].names[j].Name)
          }
        }
      }
      let len =data.length;                     
      for(let i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
        this.mainBarChartLabels.push(data[i].date)
        if(data[i].names.length==0){ 
          for(let z=0;z<a.length;z++){
            data[z].push(0);
          }   
        }
        else
        {
          for(let g=0;g<a.length;g++){
            let name1=0;
            for(let j=0;j<data[i].names.length;j++)
            {
              if(data[i].names[j].Name==unique[g])
              {
                name1=data[i].names[j].count;
                break;
              }
            }
            data[g].push(name1); 
          }
        }        
      }  
      var color1=['#333','#707070','#999999','#555555','#777777']
      for(let g=0;g<a.length;g++){
      this.mainBarChartData.push({label:a[g], data:data[g], backgroundColor:color1[g]}) 
      } 
      console.log(this.mainBarChartData)
    })
  }
```

This is how it comes on load(1)
This is how I needed it(2)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4Ckn.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TefIR.png

Is there anyway by which it can be done, Automatically an array is created on load for the undefined legend

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the legend filter function, here you can check if the data array has a length of 0, if this is the case hide it like the example below:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 0],
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"]
      },
      {
        label: '# of Counts',
        data: [],
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"]
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        labels: {
          filter: (legendItem, chartData) => (chartData.datasets[legendItem.datasetIndex].data.length !== 0)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.1.0/chart.js" integrity="sha512-LlFvdZpYhQdASf4aZfSpmyHD6+waYVfJRwfJrBgki7/Uh+TXMLFYcKMRim65+o3lFsfk20vrK9sJDute7BUAUw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```